# How to choose a position of "also" in a sentence?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

The following context confused me:

> **Man 1:** I have a bike. I *also have* a car (as a modification).
>
> **Man 2:** I have a bike. I *have also* a car (as modification).
>
> **Man 3:** I have a bike. I *have* a car *also* (as modification).

Which, among the three, is\are correct?

Answer (score 3):

> I have a bike. I also have a car.

That is the correct one, as **also** comes *before* the main verb when it is in a present or past tense.

**Also** comes *after* the verb if it was a verb "to be" (am, is, are, was, were), auxiliary verb (be, do, have), or modal verb (may, might, can, could...etc).

Example on verb "to be":

> He is tall, and he is **also** handsome.

Example on auxiliary verb:

> The teacher asked the student to write about his favorite animal. He had **also** asked him to bring a picture of it.

Example on modal verb:

> She forgot her notebook in the classroom, and she might **also** forget her pen there.

[Reference](https://www.google.ps/amp/s/oilpatchwriting.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/placement-of-also-in-sentence/amp/)

Comment: I think that Man 3 is correct, too, if there is a comma after `car`. But Man 1 is the most correct, I agree.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for help. Now, --I am a boy. I also am a student.-- as "am" here is not an auxiliary verb. am I correct, sir, in this context ,please reply.

Comment: @Kumar sadhu - "am" is verb "to be", so **also** has to come after it. "I am a boy. I am **also** a student".